# getaddrinfo() return both ipv4 and ipv6 while local system has ipv4 only

Tags: ipv6, system-calls, domain, ipv4

I use `getaddrinfo(3)` to get list ip address from a domain which support both ipv4 and ipv6, but the local system support ipv4 only or both ipv4 & ipv6, As I expect, if system support both ipv4 & ipv6 `getaddrinfo(3)` will query both ipv4 & ipv6 and if system support ipv4 only, `getaddrinfo(3)` will query only ipv4.
I try to set `ai_flags` to `AI_ADDRCONFIG` but it still query both ipv4 & ipv6 while system support ipv4 only. How should I do

Here is my code:

```
struct addrinfo hint, *res = NULL, *p = NULL;
int err;
ACE_OS::memset(&hint, 0, sizeof hint);
hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hint.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;
err = ACE_OS::getaddrinfo(hostname.c_str() ,"http", &hint, &res);
```

Comment: Did you try "hint.ai_family = AF_INET;"?

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only want IPv4, set `ai_family` to `AF_INET`.

Use `AF_INET` for IPv4, `AF_INET6` for IPv6.